# How to edit Initial Catalog of Connection String at runtime in Fsharp?

Tags: f#, connection-string, app-config, configurationmanager

Below is my Sample Connection string:

```xml
<add name="Key1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=;User ID=userXyz;Password=xxxx3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Inside which i want to update `Initial Catalog=;` to `Initial Catalog=SomeDBName;`, all this during Runtime.

Comment: What is your application? When do you connect to database? It is up to connection code to use that connectionString or any other string. Just before connecting to database you can pick connectionString saved in configuration file and extend it by your custom values.

Comment: There aren't enough details here for anyone to give you a good answer. Please edit your question and include more details, like a code sample of how you're currently connecting. Not the whole code, just the relevant parts. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.